# Desktop bridge app fails to launch from scheduled task when "Run whether user is logged on or not" is selected

Tags: desktop-bridge

We converted our .NET desktop application with the Desktop App Converter Tool. 
   The app needs to run from the scheduled task whether user is logged on or not. We first tried to run the app from the scheduled task when the user is logged on. We created a protocol for the app and using that protocol we successfully invoked the app from the task scheduler with some arguments. Using this approach when we tried to invoke the app from the task scheduler by selecting the option "Run whether user is logged on or not" i.e. session 0, the app failed to launch.

How can we invoke the UWP desktop bridge app from the task scheduler when the user is logged on or not i.e. session 0 / non-interactive session?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a [startup task](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2017/02/23/supporting-launch-at-startup-in-a-desktop-app-converted-with-the-desktop-bridge/). The article linked in my answer has an example and more details.

[Here are more docs from Microsoft on startup tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-extensions#executable). From what I can see in these docs you are allowed to execute a startup task only after the user logs in.

Answer (score 0):

Your Desktop Bridge app can not run code without the user being logged in. Running in session 0 / non-interactive session is not supported.